# JWT authentication always return 401 HTTP Error asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I keep getting the same error every time I try to login, which is 401 Http error. I am using JWT for authentication.

Below is my startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DBCS")));
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddSingleton<EmailHelper>();
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        services.AddTransient<IProductService, ProductService>();
        services.AddTransient<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
        services.AddTransient<ISelectListService, SelectListService>();
        services.AddTransient<ITokenService, TokenService>();
        services.AddTransient<UserResolverService>();
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(180);
        });

        var secretKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:key"]);
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(jwt =>
        {
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:key"]);
            jwt.SaveToken = true;
            jwt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                RequireExpirationTime = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true
            };
        });

        //Localization
        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

        services.AddMvc()
             .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
             .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
             {
                 options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                     factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource));
             });

        services.AddMvc()
           .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
           .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
           {
               options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                   factory.Create(typeof(SharedResource));
           });

    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
    {
        var culture_en = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
        //var culture_ar = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ar-JO");
        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            culture_en,
            //culture_ar,
        };

        options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US", uiCulture: "en-US");
        options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        options.RequestCultureProviders = new[]{ new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider{
                IndexOfCulture=1,
                IndexofUICulture=1
            }};
        });
        services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.ConstraintMap.Add("culture", typeof(LanguageRouteConstraint));
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        //app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Error");
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "LocalizedAreas",
                pattern: "{culture=en}/{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "Areas",
                pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "LocalizedDefault",
                pattern: "{culture=en}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{*catchall}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "RedirectToDefaultLanguage", culture = "en" });
        });
    }

    public class LanguageRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            if (!values.ContainsKey("culture"))
                return false;

            var culture = values["culture"].ToString();
            return culture == "en" || culture == "ar";
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my controller called Account, which makes sure the user exists and generates a token accordingly:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginVM model)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
    if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password))
    {
        var authClaim = new List<Claim> {
            new Claim("Id", user.CustomerId.ToString()),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        };
        var JWTtoken = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: _configuration["JWT:issuer"],
            audience: _configuration["JWT:audience"],
            claims: authClaim.AsEnumerable<Claim>(),
            expires: new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(90)).DateTime,
                    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configuration["JWT:key"])), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
        );
        var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(JWTtoken);
        if (token != null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Profile", new { area = "Store" });
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", (string)_localizer["InvalidLogin"]);
            return View(model);
        }
    }
    ModelState.AddModelError("", (string)_localizer["InvalidLogin"]);
    return View(model);
}
```

After the token is generated I redirect the user to his/her profile, below is the profile controller:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[Area("Store")]
public class ProfileController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your code doesn't show how the client retrieves the token or how the server validates the token.

Comment: `Login` doesn't return the token to the caller. Are you debugging into the code, copying `token` manually, and assigning it somewhere for testing?

Comment: As Tom W said, you need copy beer token to header(or any other ways) when you call another authorized request. Otherwise you will always return 401. Besides, you set false for `ValidateIssuer` and `ValidateAudience`, so it is no need add audience and issuer in `JWTtoken`.

Comment: Also, if you use mvc, I think cookie authentication is a better way. Jwt token authentication is better for web api project.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your comments and help, I went online and found a solution for the problem. I solved it by adding the following in Startup class, Configure method:

```
app.UseSession();
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                var token = context.Session.GetString("token");
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
                {
                    context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                }
                await next();
            });
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints()
```